# In C++, how to use macros to define a vriable under a namespace

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, directive

Here is the case. I want to substitue `ComplexDouble` type and `Double` type to `ComplexFloat` and `Float` type in one of my files depend on a variables' value.
An example here:
Original code:

```
Tensor& float_power_out(Tensor& result, const Tensor& base, const Tensor& exp) {
  auto dtype = (at::isComplexType(base.scalar_type()) || at::isComplexType(exp.scalar_type())) ?
                at::kComplexDouble : at::kDouble;
  TORCH_CHECK(result.scalar_type() == dtype,
              "the output given to float_power has dtype ", result.scalar_type(),
              " but the operation's result requires dtype ", dtype);

  return at::pow_out(result, base.to(dtype), exp.to(dtype));
}
```

What I expect to do (This is wrong)

```
#ifdef __NO_DOUBLE__
#define at::kComplexDouble at::kComplexFloat
#define at::kDouble at::kFloat
#endif
Tensor& float_power_out(Tensor& result, const Tensor& base, const Tensor& exp) {
  auto dtype = (at::isComplexType(base.scalar_type()) || at::isComplexType(exp.scalar_type())) ?
                at::kComplexDouble : at::kDouble;
  TORCH_CHECK(result.scalar_type() == dtype,
              "the output given to float_power has dtype ", result.scalar_type(),
              " but the operation's result requires dtype ", dtype);

  return at::pow_out(result, base.to(dtype), exp.to(dtype));
}

#ifdef __NO_DOUBLE__
#undef at::kComplexDouble
#undef at::kDouble
#endif
```

But using VSCode C++ Intellisense, it informs me that the usage is wrong. It tells me that in my code `at::kComplexDouble` that `the global scope has no "kDouble"`. I think its due to that in my `#define at::kComplexDouble at::kComplexFloat` statement, the `::` actually get separated out from `at`. But I don't know how to write the correct syntax, I tried to add some `##` token concatenations, but not doing it right, I guess. So, how to do this?

My worst choice is do it like this if I ever need a substition

```
Tensor& float_power_out(Tensor& result, const Tensor& base, const Tensor& exp) {
#ifdef __NO_DOUBLE__
  auto dtype = (at::isComplexType(base.scalar_type()) || at::isComplexType(exp.scalar_type())) ?
                at::kComplexFloat : at::kFloat;
#else
  auto dtype = (at::isComplexType(base.scalar_type()) || at::isComplexType(exp.scalar_type())) ?
                at::kComplexDouble : at::kDouble;
#endif
  TORCH_CHECK(result.scalar_type() == dtype,
              "the output given to float_power has dtype ", result.scalar_type(),
              " but the operation's result requires dtype ", dtype);

  return at::pow_out(result, base.to(dtype), exp.to(dtype));
}
```

But there will be 20 occurances of `at::kComplexDouble` in my file.

Ok, I have also tried to use `using` statement to do the substitution, but C++ Intellisense kept telling me my usage is wrong, here is what I tried so far:

```
#ifdef __NO_DOUBLE__
// #define at##::##kComplexDouble at##::##kComplexFloat
// #define at##::##kDouble at##::##kFloat
// #define toComplexDouble toComplexFloat
// #define toDouble toFloat
using at::kComplexFloat = at::kComplexDouble;
using at::kFloat = at::kDouble;
#endif
Tensor& float_power_out(Tensor& result, const Tensor& base, const Tensor& exp) {
  auto dtype = (at::isComplexType(base.scalar_type()) || at::isComplexType(exp.scalar_type())) ?
                at::kComplexDouble : at::kDouble;
  TORCH_CHECK(result.scalar_type() == dtype,
              "the output given to float_power has dtype ", result.scalar_type(),
              " but the operation's result requires dtype ", dtype);

  return at::pow_out(result, base.to(dtype), exp.to(dtype));
}
```

It kept telling me `qualified name is not allowed`, and `c10::kComplexDouble is not a type name` error.

Besides, I don't know how to limit the range of `using` satements, meaning I don't want  `at::kFloat` to mean `at::kDouble` anymore after some blocks of code here.

Edited:
Thanks for the answer provided by @molbdnilo. Besides, I just find that there are also some functions I need to substitute to `float` versions. For example, function calling `toComplexDouble()` and `toDouble()`, I want it to actually call `toComplexFloat()` and `toFloat()` if I defined my `__NO_DOUBLE__` macro. So, would it work if I write it like this:

```
#ifdef __NO_DOUBLE__
#define toComplexDouble toComplexFloat
#define toDouble toFloat


...
#ifdef __NO_DOUBLE__
#undef toComplexDouble
#undef toDouble
```

Is the `#undef` needed here?

Edit:
Now I just figured out how not to include the namespace operators `::` in my macro define statements, here is my solution, I think I need minimal code changes comparing to using `const auto` solution. Is this use case of macros bad practice?

```
#ifdef __NO_DOUBLE__
#define kComplexDouble kComplexFloat
#define kDouble kFloat
#define toComplexDouble toComplexFloat
#define toDouble toFloat
#endif
Tensor& float_power_out(Tensor& result, const Tensor& base, const Tensor& exp) {
  auto dtype = (at::isComplexType(base.scalar_type()) || at::isComplexType(exp.scalar_type())) ?
                at::kComplexDouble : at::kDouble;
  TORCH_CHECK(result.scalar_type() == dtype,
              "the output given to float_power has dtype ", result.scalar_type(),
              " but the operation's result requires dtype ", dtype);

  return at::pow_out(result, base.to(dtype), exp.to(dtype));
}

...
#ifdef __NO_DOUBLE__
#undef kComplexDouble
#undef kDouble
#undef toComplexDouble
#undef toDouble
#endif
```

Comment: You can't have colons in your macro names, choose another name

Comment: @AlanBirtles, but I just want to substitute `at::kDouble` to `at::kFloat`. They are defined under `at` namespace.

Comment: You can't do that with the processor

Comment: @AlanBirtles, ok. But is there any other solutions? My worst choice is to use `#ifdef __NO_DOUBLE__` everywhere this substitution is needed in this file. That would probably need 20 repetitions.

Comment: Why we need macros? What about `using`? We have 2021 and K&R C is a bit outdated...

Comment: Yes, just use a macro name with no colons in it

Comment: I just edited my question to include my worst implmentation. @Klaus, I don't know how to do that. Actually I did try to use using, but the C++ Intellisense kept telling me my usage is wrong. Let me write down my usage of `using`

Answer (score 3):

You can't have `::` in a macro name.
Don't use macros, use variables with the desired values.

```
#ifdef __NO_DOUBLE__
const auto atComplex = at::kComplexFloat
const auto atFloat = at::kFloat
#else
const auto atComplex = at::kComplexDouble
const auto atFloat = at::kDouble
#endif

Tensor& float_power_out(Tensor& result, const Tensor& base, const Tensor& exp) {
  auto dtype = (at::isComplexType(base.scalar_type()) || at::isComplexType(exp.scalar_type())) 
               ? atComplex : atFloat;
  TORCH_CHECK(result.scalar_type() == dtype,
              "the output given to float_power has dtype ", result.scalar_type(),
              " but the operation's result requires dtype ", dtype);

  return at::pow_out(result, base.to(dtype), exp.to(dtype));
}
```

You could do the same thing with macros,

```
#ifdef __NO_DOUBLE__
#define atComplex at::kComplexFloat
#define atFloat at::kFloat
#else
#define atComplex at::kComplexDouble
#define atFloat at::kDouble
#endif
```

but why use macros when you don't need them?

You can do similar aliasing with functions:

```
#ifdef __NO_DOUBLE__
type1 toAtComplex(type2 t) { return at::toComplexFloat(t); }
#else
type1 toAtComplex(type2 t) { return at::toComplexDouble(t); }
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just found there is also something else I need to substitute, some functions, e.g. `toComplexDouble()`, I want it to be `toComplexFloat()`, and `toDouble()` to be `toFloat()`. So this time, I have to use macros, right? Or any more eligant solution?

Comment: You can just conditionally define functions that forward to the ones you want. Any half-decent compiler from this millennium will inline the calls and it will cost nothing. (Don't think "I want to conditionally replace X with Y", think "I want some Z that can conditionally mean either X or Y".)

Comment: Can you give me an example. It's kinda abstract. I will edit my question.

Comment: Now there's a third example. (You're still "do this instead of that", when you should be "do either this or that". They are different mindsets.)

Comment: OK, I get it. Thanks for sharing this wisdom. But I still don't understand why in this situation, using macros is not a good choice. I understand that macros don't do type check stuff. But I can write minimal code changes if I use macros. And they are only working in this file( see my updates in a moment on my workaround), so they are not 'unsafe'? I mean, I don't have to create another variable Z and change all my code X with Z.